# return type in database constructor

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am creating database connection to SQLite in android app. 
the connection is giving error . as i have to make the login part.

```
public class DatabaseConnection extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "App1";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

    public Connection(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

here is the full class.

```
   public Connection(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

this part is giving error.
How to fix it?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java class. I suspect that the class name is not `Connection`.

Comment: I have added the whole class now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor name needs to match the Java class name. Your class is `DatabaseConnection`. Your constructor is `Connection`. These are not the same. Rename one to match the other.